# Python pip console scripts alternative for windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, command-line-interface, pypi

**Like we have `console scripts` option that we use in `setup.py`, to configure a direct cli python application for Linux command line.**

**How we can create a CLI App for windows, that could just be installed with `pip install` command (for powershell / cmd) ?**

### What answers I want:

- The above question (main, ***imp***)
- A good `setup.py` code, means I'm new a bit in packaging (& Pypi) thing
- what to write in side `__init__.py`
- Package File Structure

Comment: Mayve try `gui_scripts`: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html?highlight=gui#console-scripts

Comment: "In addition to console_scripts, Setuptools supports gui_scripts, which will launch a GUI application without running in a terminal window." - the website mentions. I want to run cli (not gui) in windows with direct pip install as it happens in linux (when u install a cli app from pip install).

Comment: Ah... I misread. Then `console_scripts` is what you need. It should work on Windows same as on Linux. What have you tried? What did not work?

Comment: For me its not working in any of my windows (10), you can try - type 'pip install justhacking' - in linux terminal - if u now type 'justhacking' (in terminal) it works as cli app. But when u do same in windows cmd (or powershell) it says ['justhacking' is not recognized ...]

Comment: Might be an issue with `PATH` environment variable. The `justhacking` executable is most likely installed in a directory that is not listed in your `PATH` environment variable. -- Are you using virtual environments? -- Maybe you could also consider using [_`pipx`_](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) which makes installing Python CLI tools much more user friendly.

Comment: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages` is the location where 'justhacking' package files are stored in windows (for linux `/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`), so u might be right about `PATH` variables - need to research (if someone knows pls write down here)